# How to solve $P(n,n−2) = 360$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

Is my solution correct? Thanks

$$\begin{align*}P(n,n−2) & = 360 \\
    \dfrac{n!}{(n-r)!} &  = 360 \\
    \dfrac{n!}{(n-(n-2))!} & = 360 \\
    \dfrac{n!}{(n-n+2)!} & = 360 \\
    \dfrac{n!}{2\cdot 1} & = 360 \\
    2\left(\dfrac{n!}{2}\right) & = 2(360) \\
    n! & = 720\end{align*}$$

$6!=720$
So,

$$n!=6! \\
    \dfrac{n!}{1!} = \dfrac{6!}{1!}$$

Answer:  $n=6$

Comment: What's the purpose of the passage $x!/1! = 6!/1!$ ?

Comment: I dont know if my solution is correct here    "  n!/1! = 6!/1!  "  I want to eliminate the factorial in n!=6!

Comment: That is not quite how you eliminate the factorial. Instead, you can use the fact that the factorial is strictly increasing over the natural numbers greater than $0$. You can prove this using the following argument: Let $a<b$ be positive integers. You can write $b = a+k$ for some positive integer $k$. Then, $b! = (a+k)! = (a+k)(a+k-1)\cdots (a+2)(a+1)a! > a!$. Since the factorial is strictly increasing, it is one-to-one (for numbers greater than $0$). Therefore, any solution found is necessarily the only solution. In fact, the only equality among natural numbers is $0!=1! = 1$

Comment: Thanks, But how can i simplify this: " n!=6! " to get the value of " n "  or make n=6?

Comment: The fact is that two different natural numbers cannot have the same factorial. Hence $n!=6!$ can have only one solution i.e. $6$.

Comment: @Anonymous apart from the special case of $0! = 1!$

Comment: Is $0$ an natural number?

Comment: @Anonymous depends on the book you look at. For example, the ISO 80000-2:2009 standard included zero in the set of natural numbers. I am not sure if this was updated in the 2019 update to this standard.

Comment: The factorial is injective on $[1,\infty)$. I.e, $\forall x_1,x_2\geq 1$, $x_1!=x_2!\implies x_1=x_2$